# square loss function in classification

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

I know the the square loss function in the regression context as follows:

$(y-f(x))^2$

for y the real, and f(x) the predicted value. This formulation is quite easy to understand: We have a convex loss function where the loss is based on the difference between real and predicted values, and outliers are penalized heavier by squaring this difference.

What I don't understand however is the following formulation as often found in a classification context:

$L(f(x),y) = (1 - y*f(x))^2$

First of all, we do not calculate the difference between real and predicted value, but multiply them - why? Given e.g. that both values would be large, would this amount to a large loss..? Secondly, for a binary classification problem, a missclassification where y = -1 and f(x) = 1, it seems that the loss would also equate to 4? Lastly, why to we have to subtract the product y*f(x) from 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few subtleties to the notation / standardization that are being missed.

Firstly, "1" in your expression for $L$ does not mean the scalar value 1: it means the all 1's vector. Similarly, $f(x)$ means the vector of $f$'s values at each data point, and $y$ is the corresponding vector of true (desired) values at each data point. The squaring is really 'sum of squares' -- or you can think of the squaring as dotting the vector with itself.

When (at one data point) $y = -1$ and $f = 1$, then $(1 - y * f)^2 = (1 + 1)^2 = 4$, a penalty. When $y = 1$ and $f = 1$, then $(1 - y*f)^2 = (1 - 1)^2 = 0$, indicating a perfect match and thus no penalty.

You can indeed show that this formulation is equivalent to the standard (in other areas) formulation of $(y-f(x))^2$:

$$({\bf 1} - y * f)^2 = {\bf 1}\cdot{\bf 1} - 2{\bf 1}\cdot(y * f) + (y*f)^2$$

The ${\bf 1}\cdot{\bf 1}$ is a constant and so irrelevant to the fit. ${\bf 1}\cdot(y*f) = y\cdot f$, as you can easily verify by inspecting the sum. And when $y$ consists entirely of $\pm 1$, then any factor of $y^2 = 1$, so the last term is just $f^2$ -- resulting in $-2 y\cdot f + f^2$. Compare with,

$$(y-f)^2 = y^2 - 2y\cdot f + f^2$$

Now again the leading $y^2$ is a constant that can be dropped, and the rest of the terms match up.

But, why in the field of machine learning is the $(1-yf)^2$ format preferred, if it's equivalent? In curve fitting, a sum-of-squares penalty makes a lot of sense: add up the error on each one. There are real valued errors and they are scaled appropriately. Machine learning is much more focused on classification which has a strict "yes"/"no" interpretation. The vector $y*f$ then indicates if something was correct or not, and is often manipulated different ways. $({\bf 1}-y*f)^2$ is one loss function; other popular ones are $\sum\log(1+y*f)$, also called perplexity; or $\sum\textrm{sign}(y*f)$, which is just accuracy.

Comment: Thx for the clarifications! Two additional questions: For regression, f is the predictive function (mapping the data onto the regression line). Is it be correct to call it the kernel function in the Machine Learning context? E.g. mapping data onto the hyperplane? Also, I see that in the context of SVMs, $y*f(x)$ is called the margin - i.e. the (preferably maximal) distance between the closest two datapoints from different classes - but in how far does $y*f(x)$ represent a margin? Is this insofar the case as that Hinge loss penalizes everything larger than $y*f(x)$?

Comment: I don't think it's really correct to call $f$ the kernel function, no, as it's not a similarity metric or adding a dimension or anything -- it's the full classifier. I don't think it's quite right to call $y*f(x)$ a margin, either. Given two sets of data that can be separated, there is some "in between" region, and that is the margin; any new data in the margin would be very ambiguous, which set it should be classified as. The margin equations just happen to have similar mathematical form to $y*f(x)$. It's the 'margin' because it's the 'gap' between YES's and NO's in the training data.

Comment: Clear regarding f(x). I read about y*f(x) as margin in several places, e.g.: "The margin on an example (x,y) is yf(x). The margin is a measure of how correct we are". Source slide 5: https://davidrosenberg.github.io/ml2015/docs/3a.loss-functions.pdf.

Comment: Ah, okay, I guess that is a slightly different sense of 'margin'. Here they have the dividing hyperplane, in a sense, already 'fixed': It's where f=0. The 'margin' is then how far away from that we are. Well, $f$'s magnitude is how far away we are, but we care about if we're on the right or the wrong side of that. Multiplying by $y$ (which is $\pm 1$) will optionally flip $f$ to give us a meaningful sign. So a larger value of $yf$ means we're more firmly on the correct side, a greater 'margin of safety' in our prediction. If $yf$ is negative, we have negative margin of safety: we're wrong.

Comment: Got it, thx for all:)